# How to listen to tweets from people you are following on Android?

Tags: android, tweets

I want to create an app which would parse all the tweets from following people. Can I create something like a broadcast receiver, which would be invoked when new tweet is posted?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into what you can do with the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public)

And probably set it up with some kind of web hook